# Redirect URLs ending with .php to new URL in Laravel & Nginx

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I am migrating from my legacy code to Laravel code. The legacy code was on simple php pages and hence, all my pages have .php extension when I visit them on URL : [www.example.com/page.php](http://www.example.com/page.php).

Now in Laravel, it has changed to something else: [www.example.com/my-page](http://www.example.com/my-page)

I used the below code in Routes to redirect old extension to new page

```
Route::redirect('page.php', '/my-page', 301); // 301 by default
```

This does not work! It gives me error:
[image: On visiting the URL www.example.com/page.php on new laravel server, it gives below error]

On my Nginx Log, below is the error

```
2020/07/13 14:53:25 [error] 22935#22935: *70072 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 110.227.222.202, server: example.com, request: "GET /page.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock:", host: "example.com"
```

How to solve this requirement: Redirect 301 all the legacy pages ( there are 1000s of it) with .php extension to completely new URL structure.

Below is my NGINX Conf

```
# Expires map
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  epoch;
    text/css                   max;
    application/javascript     max;
    ~image/                    max;
}

 server {
   expires $expires;

    server_name example.com;

    root /var/www/example.com/html/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

     location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}


        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi.conf;
            }
    }


server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Comment: Can you share your nginx .conf files?

Comment: HI @KurtFriars - Added Nginx file above